# How to access request data in subscriber in shopware 6

Tags: request, shopware, subscriber, shopware6

I have built a subscriber in my plugin for Shopware 6 that subscribes to `'framework.validation.address.create' => 'onAddressCreation'` event in order to add extra validation definition. But I also need to be able to access request data in the subscriber action.

How can I do that?
So far I have managed to inject `Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService` in the subscriber constructor and the subsriber action receives `Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\BuildValidationEvent` but there is no way to get to the address fields with those two classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot pass the request from a controller or the request is not shipped with the event, you might want to inject the `request_stack` Symfony service
https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container/request.html

Comment: What is the difference between Request and RequestStack?